# Refine search results of array with numbers and strings

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm looking to improve on my current search function for an app I'm making.

I'm currently fetching an array of objects from a firebase query which look like this

```
{
   make: "make",
   model: "model",
   year: 2002,
   gas: "petrol",
   mileage: "mileage",
   images: {
       image1: "url",
       image2: "url"
   },
   price: 1295
}
```

I currently filter through the array using the filter method and compare an object that contains the refinements against the original array like this

```
refine = (refinements, currentResults) => {
        return currentResults.filter(result => this.matchesAll(refinements, result));
}

matchesAll = (refinements, result) => {
        for (const key in refinements) {
            if (refinements[key] !== result[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

This works great for comparing the fields which contain strings, however if the user wants to check for a minimum age or maximum price, I don't know how to implement this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a field to describe the type of comparison You want to carry out:  "min", "max" or "equal":

```
    //----refinements could be:

    {
    "price":
        {   "type":"max",
            "value":1000
        },
    "age":
        {   "type":"min",
            "value":18
        },
    "name":
        {   "type":"eq",
            "value":'dsjkds'
        },
    ...
    }
```

And your filters:

```
    refine = (refinements, currentResults) => {
            return currentResults.filter(result => this.matchesAll(refinements, result));
    }

    matchesAll = (refinements, result) => {
            for (const key in refinements) {
                if(refinements[key]['type'] === 'min'){
                    if (refinements[key] > result[key]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }else if(refinements[key]['type'] === 'max'){
                    if (refinements[key] < result[key]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }else{
                    if (refinements[key] !== result[key]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @dev8080, Thanks for responding, I thought about doing it a similar way but was structuring it differently to how you have which was resulting in inaccurate results. This looks perfect. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: @juicy89 No problem. Anytime.